# Setting up webpack/HMR for Shopify development

Tags: javascript, webpack, shopify, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I am trying to setup webpack's dev server and HMR to work with Shopify theme development. When running the server and opening the local IP, I get this error from Shopify's DNS provider, CloudFlare.

[image]

**How can I properly setup webpack to inject hot changes (css/JS) to my proxied Shopify store (the mystore.myshopify.com url)?**

My webpack config as follows:

```
const path = require("path");
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: false,
    hot: true,    
    https: true,
    proxy: {
      "**": { 
        target: "http://mystore.myshopify.com", 
        secure: false
      }
    },    
  },  
  entry: "./src/scripts/index.js",
  output: { 
    filename: "./app.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  plugins: [

  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          //postcss here (autoprefixer, babel etc)
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposed solution for hot reloading with webpack and shopify.

In your package.json you will want the following scripts

1. A webpack build script that watches for changes. I have also added a progress parameter so I can see when it updates. This will be watching your /src folder for changes.

   "webpack:build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --watch --progress",
2. A shopify theme serve script that uploads the theme files from a /dist folder that is the output of a webpack build.

   "shopify:serve": "cd dist && shopify theme serve"
3. You can link these two scripts together into one using the following.

   "deploy:serve": "run-p -sr webpack:build shopify:serve"

So what happens is the webpack build script listens for changes in your /src code. When a change is main it re-builds the output to the /dist folder that shopify theme serve is listening on. When that updates, shopify uploads the changes.

Voila.

Here is the repo for this implementation if you want to play around - https://github.com/Sambuxc/9119-shopify-theme/

As of writing this, my dev versions are:
Node 18.7.0
Npm 8.15.0
Shopify Cli 2.21.0

Good luck and I hope this helps future developers.

Please reach out to me with any further questions if you get stuck.